# Where are Recipient Status codes documented?

Tags: docusignapi

Where can I find the recipient status codes (created, delivered, etc.) and the status's meaning?

I've tried various Google searches and went through the [REST API documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list), but I can't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DocuSign Developer Center for the REST API family you can go to the **Guides** -> **Features** -> **Recipients** page which has the list of recipient statuses.  See the following page:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/recipients#recipient-statuses

For reference, here are the statuses listed on the above page:

`created`: The recipient is in a draft state. This is only associated with draft envelopes (envelopes with a Created status).

`sent`: The recipient has been sent an email notification that it is their turn to sign an envelope.

`delivered`: The recipient has viewed the document(s) in an envelope through the DocuSign signing web site. This is not an email delivery of the documents in an envelope.

`signed`: The recipient has completed (signed) all required tags in an envelope. This is a temporary state during processing, after which the recipient is automatically moved to Completed.

`declined`: The recipient declined to sign the document(s) in the envelope.

`completed`: The recipient has completed their actions (signing or other required actions if not a signer) for an envelope.

`faxpending`: The recipient has finished signing and the system is waiting a fax attachment by the recipient before completing their signing step.

`autoresponded`: The recipient's email system auto-responded (bounced-back) to the email from DocuSign. This status is used in the web console to inform senders about the bounced-back email.